# jquery show hide the requested page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Problem is to show/hide requested specific page from among pages in the html. The code I tried is shown below. Can any one point me the right direction. I n the blow code I tried to show only pagethree, but it displayed pageone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   

<script>
$("#pageone").hide();
$("#pagetwo").hide();
$("#pagethree").show();
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page one</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>page one contents </p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>page one</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page two</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>page two contents</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>page two</h1>
  </div>
</div> 



<div data-role="page" id="pagethree">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page three</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>page three contents...</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>page three</h1>
  </div>
</div> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code and the below answers are wrong. Show/hide isn't your solution. You need to use `pagebeforechange` event.

Comment: Are you using JQM 1.4? Because the solution is lightly different now.

Comment: No, I am using JQM 1.2.

Comment: this is better http://jsfiddle.net/20L0kLzL/ I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent page from showing or redirect a user before *next page* is shown, you need to listen to `pagebeforechange` event. This event fires before changing page transition is commenced and *URL History* is updated.

When `pagebeforechange` is emitted, it omits a *data object* holding details of previous and next page. Use this data to determine from and which pages the user is navigating.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    var nextPage = data.toPage,
        prevPage = data.options.fromPage;
    if (typeof nextPage === "object" && typeof prevPage === "undefined") {
        var page = nextPage[0].id;
        if (page === "pageone") {
            $.mobile.changePage("#pagethree", {
                transition: "flip"
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Using `.show()` or `.hide()` will get you nowhere. In addition, refrain from using `.ready()` or `$(function () {});` in jQuery Mobile and use *Page Events* instead.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5sP55/)**

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your code inside **[pagecreate](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)** event:

> Triggered when the page has been created in the DOM (via ajax or
>   other) and after all widgets have had an opportunity to enhance the
>   contained markup.

```
<script>
$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {
    $("#pageone").hide();
    $("#pagetwo").hide();
    $("#pagethree").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: `pagecreate` or `.ready` aren't the mafi  words that will make any code work properly. You should understand how JQM works before posting entirely wrong answers.

Comment: Instead of going around and criticize people, why don't you just post an answer to help OP?

Comment: I don't think anyone will post an answer If they knew it was wrong.

Comment: document ready must work. I always do it. And I always check my answer before it post. http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/PaGA4/

Comment: omar's code worked PERFECTLY. after reading the manual I figured out that I had to used page events but couldn't make the logic. sajitha you are wrong because the pages lost their css formatting. nobody has the jqm knowledge who answered here!

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#pageone").hide();
$("#pagetwo").hide();
$("#pagethree").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This work for me. Why down vote??? See JSFEDEL http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/PaGA4/